# doctest in class don't pass

Tags: python

I have a class name "vector" and I need to implemente some methodes.
I have built-in 'doctest.testmod()' in the code. I wrote all the methodes (beside str and repr) I need but I don't understand why am I getting all these failures.
I would be greatfull if anypne can help.
tnx.

```
from math import sqrt

class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):        
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z

    def to_tuple(self):
        '''
        >>> Vector(1,0,0).to_tuple()
        (1, 0, 0)
        '''
        return (self.x,self.y,self.z)

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        __str__
        >>> str(Vector(1.0, 0.0, 1.0))
        '(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)'
        '''
        return str(self.to_tuple())

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        >>> Vector(3,6,10.) == Vector(3.,6.,10)
        True
        >>> Vector(1,0.,-1.) == Vector(1.,0.,1)
        False
        '''
        if self.x==other[0] and self.y==other[1] and self.z==other[2]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __add__(self, other):      
        '''
        >>> Vector(1,2,3) + Vector(0.5,3,-1)
        (1.5, 5, 2)
        '''  
        return (self.x+other[0],self.y+other[1],self.z+other[2])

    def __neg__(self):
        '''
        >>> -Vector(1,8,-4.3)
        (-1, -8, 4.3)
        '''
        return (self.x*-1,self.y*-1,self.z*-1)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        '''
        >>> Vector(1,2,3) - Vector(0.5,3,-1)
        (0.5, -1, 4)
        '''
        self.__add__(other.__neg__)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        '''
        >>> Vector(1,5,3) * 2
        (2, 10, 6)
        >>> Vector(1,5,3) * (-0.5)
        (-0.5, -2.5, -1.5)
        '''
        if type(scalar)!=int or float:
            raise TypeError("Vector multiplication only defined for scalar")
        else:
            return (scalar*self.x,scalar*self.y,scalar*self.z)
    def inner(self, other):  
        '''
        >>> Vector(1,2,3).inner(Vector(-1,5,3))
        18
        '''     
        return (self.x*other[0]+self.y*other[1]+self.z*other[2])

    def norm(self):
        '''
        >>> Vector(0,3,4).norm()
        5.0
        '''
        return sqrt(self.inner(self))

import doctest


doctest.testmod()
```

output:

```
6 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.Vector.__add__
   2 of   2 in __main__.Vector.__eq__
   2 of   2 in __main__.Vector.__mul__
   1 of   1 in __main__.Vector.__sub__
   1 of   1 in __main__.Vector.inner
   1 of   1 in __main__.Vector.norm
***Test Failed*** 8 failures.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your doc tests are failing, but in the future, I highly recommend unit tests, if you've not tried them yet. Doc tests are very limited.

Comment: this is an assaigment I got with the tests.. but tnx BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `__add__` , `__eq__` and `__inner__` methods, you access the fields of other by index, but you should access them like `other.x, other.y, other.z`

Then, in the `__mul__` method:

`if type(scalar)!=int or float:`

should be changed with:

`if not isinstance(scalar, (int, float)):`

Comment: tnx I'll try it, but how python knows where is other.x?
its not definded

Comment: `if not isinstance(scalar, (int, float))` would be preferred

Comment: The other is expected to be a Vector which has x, y, z attribtues.

Comment: Yeah, you are right actually, I was just trying to find a better method :)

Comment: or `isinstance(scalar, numbers.Number)` from the `numbers` module, which would also work with `long`, `complex`, and `confusing` (I made the last one up)